# Empty spaces at line counter column

Tags: visual-studio

After some updates, Visual Studio started showing these empty spaces at JS files.

How to remove them?

I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 (64-bit) - Current Version 17.6.2

[image: line gap]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To remove this, I had to disable CodeLens. To achieve this: Options -> Text Editor -> All Languages -> CodeLens -> uncheck "Enable CodeLens".

At the time of my post, nothing was showed at that space; but a recent update included CodeLens message on that space. While CodeLens does help at C# code, unfortunately this doesn't seems to help at JS files.

Since Visual Studio only has a global option to enable/disable this feature, I got used to "CTRL + Q" and enable or disable CodeLens when I need.

I'm currently at 17.6.4 Visual Studio version.